Thymeleaf, get list then post object from this list
Im getting list of Order and make table with it + button next to every Item.
On click button i want to post this single Order from list to API.
The problem is when i press button, i receive on API empty object of this item with parameters 0, null, "" etc...
@GetMapping
public String findAllOrders(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("orderlist", orderService.findAll());
    return "index";
}

@PostMapping("/change")
public void setPayOrder(@ModelAttribute("order") Order order) {
    System.out.println(order);      <------ this order from sended list is empty
}

index
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
      <tr th:each="order:${orderlist}">
        <td th:text="${order.idOrder}"></td>
        <td th:text="${order.description}"></td>

        <td>
            <form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/change}" th:object="${order}">
                <button type="submit">Change pay</button>
            </form>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

So talking simple i need this:
 GetListOfItemFromApi:

 Item>button(Send this item to api)
 Item>button(Send this item to api)
 Item>button(Send this item to api)`

How can i send to api single Order from list?
